# Pytorch linear regression loss increase

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, linear-regression

I tried to implement a simple demo that gets a polynomial regression, but the linear model's loss fails to decrease.

I am confused about where I went wrong.

If I trained the model one sample(batch size = 1) each time, it works fine. but when I feed the model with many samples a time, the loss increase and get inf.

```py
import numpy as np

import torch
import math
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def rand_series(size):
    x = np.linspace(-100, 100, size)
    np.random.shuffle(x)
    base_y = 20 * np.sin(2 * math.pi / 200 * x)
    y = base_y + 10 * np.random.rand(size)
    return x, y


def rescale_vec(vector):
    vec_as_tensor = torch.tensor(vector, dtype=torch.float32)
    max_in_vec = torch.max(vec_as_tensor)
    min_in_vec = torch.min(vec_as_tensor)
    if max_in_vec - min_in_vec == 0:
        return torch.ones(vec_as_tensor.size(), dtype=torch.float32)
    else:
        return (vec_as_tensor - min_in_vec) / (max_in_vec - min_in_vec)


def rescale(vectors):
    if len(vectors.shape) == 1:
        return rescale_vec(vectors)
    nor_vecs = torch.empty(vectors.shape)
    for i in range(vectors.shape[0]):
        nor_vecs[i] = rescale_vec(vectors[i])
    return nor_vecs


class LinearRegression (torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__ (self, power=4):
        super().__init__()
        self.layer = torch.nn.Linear(power, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.layer(x)


def regression(x_, y_, learning_rate):
    x = torch.t(torch.tensor(x_, dtype=torch.float32))
    y = torch.tensor(y_, dtype=torch.float32)
    dim_size = x.size()[1]
    print(dim_size, x.size())

    model = LinearRegression(dim_size)
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
    loss_func = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='sum')
    batch_size = 400
    for round in range(50):
        sample_indices = torch.randint(0, len(x), (batch_size, ))
        x_samples = torch.index_select(x, 0, sample_indices)
        y_samples = torch.index_select(y, 0, sample_indices)
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        y_hat = model(x_samples.view(-1, dim_size))
        loss = loss_func(y_hat, y_samples)
        print(loss.item())
        loss.backward()

        optimizer.step()

    return model



x_one, y = rand_series(1000)
b = np.ones(len(x_one))
x = np.array([b, x_one, x_one ** 2, x_one ** 3, x_one ** 4, x_one ** 5])

model = regression(rescale(x), torch.tensor(y, dtype=torch.float32), 0.002)

nor_x = rescale(x)

y_hat = model(torch.t(torch.tensor(x, dtype=torch.float32)))
plt.scatter(x_one, y)
plt.scatter(x_one, y_hat.data, c='red')
plt.show()
```

the loss:

```
4.7375866968775066e+19
1.6979300048622735e+26
6.0214270068868396e+32
inf
inf
inf
```

Comment: Your code blocks are not indented correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use loss_func = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='mean') to solve the NaN problem. A batch of one or two seems to work because the loss was small enough. By adding more epochs, you should see that your loss tend exponentially to infinity.